# How to concat objects in localStorage in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

We have to concat objects to turn them into an array of objects in the HTML5 localStorage.

We first check whether there are already some data. If it is not there we only add that item or we append another item to the existing item to turn it into an array.

```
if(type === 'server'){
    var old = $window.localStorage.getItem('selectedServers');
    if(old === null)
        localStorage.setItem('selectedServers', JSON.stringify(item));
    else
        localStorage.setItem('selectedServers', JSON.stringify(old.concat(item)));
}
```

But this code does not work. Even `JSON.stringify(old+data)` gives unexpected result.

The result comes with unexpected `\`s. `item` here is the object to be added or rather appended.

How to achieve the same in Angular JS?

Comment: What is `item`?

Comment: @dfsq The new object to be added.

Comment: Why do you want to store object in one case and array in another. Store array always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse before using [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example), as you are persisting string which doesn't have `concat()` method

```
if (type === 'server') {
    var old = $window.localStorage.getItem('selectedServers');
    if (old === null) {
        var arr = [item]; //Create ARRAY
        $window.localStorage.setItem('selectedServers', JSON.stringify(arr));
    } else {
        old = JSON.parse(old);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('selectedServers', JSON.stringify(old.concat(item)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But I still see the old item. The new item after which the array length should be updated to 2, is not present. And when I do .push instead of .concat , I get the value 2 in the stringified array.

Comment: Even though in console old.concat(item) returns the modified appended value, for some reason it is not reflecting in localStorage. It is holding only the first value.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder, Thats weird, How are you checking?

Answer (score 0):

The local storage can only store strings, that's why you use `JSON.stringify`. The method `concat()` is not present in strings, so I guess you are storing a "stringified" array.
If that is the case, you have to parse the string to get the array, then concatenate the new array o(r you cand just use `push()` instead creating an array with one element), and then stringify the resulting array again.